# How can I "merge" patterns in a single line?

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

I am doing grep and sed and I get 2 lines of a file that I am interested in. How can I get these lines in a single line ending with the new line character?
Now I am getting:

```
pattern1  
pattern2
```

I would like to get `pattern1 pattern2 \n`

Comment: Can you share more of the sample data?

Comment: Use  `printf %s\\n pattern1 pattern2 | sed '$!N;s/\n/ /'`

Comment: Paste is the tool for the job, if you're intending to merge multiple lines of output into one.

Comment: any specific tool? How do you plan to do this?

Answer (score 8):

[`paste`](http://man.cx/paste):

```
{...pipeline...} | paste -d " " - -
```

That says: "read a line from stdin (the first `-`), read another line from stdin (the second `-`), then join them with a space"

---

a bash-specific technique:

```
$ x=$(grep -o pattern. test.txt)
$ echo "$x"
pattern1
pattern2
$ mapfile -t <<< "$x"
$ echo "${MAPFILE[*]}"
pattern1 pattern2
```

ref: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile

Comment: What is `- -`? Is the command like that?

Comment: @Jim - yes that's correct. Those are telling `paste` how you want it to process the input. 2 at a time. Add more to do 3 at at time. `seq 10 | paste -d " " - - `.

Answer (score 6):

I'll put three versions different methods in a row

#### AWK

```
printf %s\\n pattern1 pattern2 | awk -vRS="\n" -vORS=" " '1; END {print RS}'
```

#### SED

```
printf %s\\n pattern1 pattern2 | sed '$!N;s/\n/ /'
```

#### TR

```
printf %s\\n pattern1 pattern2 | tr '\n' ' '; echo
```

And there are many more.

Comment: The `tr` solution will swallow the ending newline, so you might want to add `; echo` to that one

Comment: @glennjackman ah right!  Thanks for the hint. You are free to modify the answer though. I missed that bit!

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using shell script or in command-line, just put the output of the command in a variable then `echo` it:

```
# x=$(grep -e "pattern1\|pattern2" test)
# printf '%s\n' "$x"
pattern1 pattern2
```

Comment: unquoted, the variable is also subject to filename expansion, so if you have any glob characters (like `*` or `?`) in the result, the values may change.

Comment: @glennjackman, thanks for mention this, how can we fix this?

Comment: @Networker by not using backticks but `$()` instead.. and using printf `printf '%s\n' "$x"`

Comment: I would expect that `printf '%s\n' "$x"` will NOT remove the "internal" newline.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`, you can do this:

```
<your previous commands> | sed '{N; s/\n/ /}'
```

- `N;` tells `sed` to add the next line into the pattern space, so now `sed` is working with both lines.
- `s/\n/ /` replaces the newline character with a space, "merging" the two lines together.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way, pipe output to `xargs`:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb' | xargs
a b
```

This only works with small ouput, because it's limited by maximum characters per command line. The largest value depends on system, you can get this value using `getconf ARG_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

```
( set -f; IFS='
'; printf '%s %s\n' $(grepcmd <input)
) >output
```

IFS will be happy to eat it if you want.

Answer (score -1):

wrap your sed/grep in backticks

when your original command was:

```
grep -i 'foo' mylog.log | sed 's/bar/baz/gi'
```

your new command would be:

```
`grep -i 'foo' mylog.log | sed 's/bar/baz/gi'`
```

Doesn't get the spaces in between lines, but you can always tack on another sed pipe:

```
 | sed 's/$/ /'
```

Comment: Uh, no. That will *execute* the output of the sed command.