# Print line range from file, and include line numbers

Tags: text-processing, sed, command-line

I have a `sed` oneliner, to print line range from a file:

```
sed -n '10,20p' file.txt
```

The above will print lines 10 to 20 from file.txt.

But how can I also print the line numbers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sed to print out the line number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526064/sed-to-print-out-the-line-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only using `sed`.

```
sed -n '10,20{=;p}' file.txt | sed '{N; s/\n/ /}'
```

- `N;` tells `sed` to add the next line into the pattern space, so now `sed` is working with both lines.
- `s/\n/ /` replaces the newline character with a space, "merging" the two lines together.

Sources :

- (1) [Numbering lines matching the pattern using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577256/numbering-lines-matching-the-pattern-using-sed)
- (2) [How can I “merge” patterns in a single line? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151613/how-can-i-merge-patterns-in-a-single-line)

Explanations by [Alaa Ali](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/38128/alaa-ali) (in source 2)

Answer (score 4):

Try `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==10,FNR==20 {print FNR ":" $0}' file.txt
```

This will print the line number, a colon, and then the line, in the range of lines 10 to 20.

Or to stop reading after line 20:

```
awk 'FNR >= 10 {print FNR ":" $0}; FNR == 20 {exit}' file.txt
```

If processing more than one file and your `awk` implementation supports the `nextfile` directive:

```
awk -v OFS=: 'FNR >= 10 {print FILENAME, FNR, $0}; FNR == 20 {nextfile}' ./*.txt
```

(here also printing the current file name).

Answer (score 2):

[`sed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) has the `=` command that prints the line number.

```
sed -n '10,20{=;p}' file.txt
```

However, it prints the line number in a separate line above
the real line.

If you want to precede the line number in the same line of
the actual line, you can pipe [`nl`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nl.html) to `sed`,

```
nl file.txt | sed -n '10,20p'
```

You may want to set some `nl` flags to make the output better. I have it aliased to `alias nl='nl -b a -n rz -s "|" -w1'`, so as to use `|` as separator between number and line, right justifying numbers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is short:

```
perl -ne '10..20 and print "$. $_"'
```

If the file is long:

```
perl -ne '10..20 and print "$. $_"; 21..22 and exit'
```

This way you stop after reading line 20.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ < file grep -ne '^' | sed -ne '10,20p'

$ < file sed -e '10,20!d;=;20q' | paste -d: - -

Not so UUOC:
$ cat -n file | sed -nEe '10,20s/^\s*(\S+)\t/\1:/p'

$ perl -lne 's/^/$.:/;
    print if 10..20;
    last  if 20..20;
' file
```